# PySpark: Inconsistency between CrossValidator.avgMetrics and the average computed from collectSubModels

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, cross-validation

I have setup a `CrossValidator` object in combination with a linear regression pipeline and a grid of hyperparameters to select from. More specifically, I run 5-fold cross validation on 9 different settings resulting from the combinations of two hyperparameters (each one taking on 3 values), and I keep track of *all* the 45 resulting models by setting the `collectSubModels` flag to `True`:

```
...

lr = LinearRegression(featuresCol="features", labelCol="label")

pipeline = Pipeline(stages=indexers + [encoder] + [assembler] + [lr])

param_grid = ParamGridBuilder()\
        .addGrid(lr.regParam, [0.0, 0.05, 0.1]) \
        .addGrid(lr.elasticNetParam, [0.0, 0.5, 1.0])\
        .build()

cross_val = CrossValidator(estimator=pipeline, 
                           estimatorParamMaps=param_grid,
                           evaluator=RegressionEvaluator(metricName="rmse"),
                           numFolds=5,
                           collectSubModels=True
                           )

# Run cross-validation, and choose the best set of parameters
cv_model = cross_val.fit(train)

return cv_model
```

Everything seems to run smoothly, except for the fact that when I'm printing out the performance (i.e., RMSE) of each model (i.e., 9 models for each fold) and I try to "manually" compute the average from each fold, the resulting 9 average values **do not** match at all with the values I get when I use the internal `avgMetrics` property of the `CrossValidator`.
Just to give you an example, the following are the 5 RMSE values I obtained using the first combination of the two hyperparameters (i.e., both set to 0):

```
*************** Fold #1 ***************
--- Model #1 out of 9 ---
    Parameters: lambda=[0.000]; alpha=[0.000] 
    RMSE: 149354.656

*************** Fold #2 ***************
--- Model #1 out of 9 ---
    Parameters: lambda=[0.000]; alpha=[0.000] 
    RMSE: 146038.521

*************** Fold #3 ***************
--- Model #1 out of 9 ---
    Parameters: lambda=[0.000]; alpha=[0.000] 
    RMSE: 148739.919

*************** Fold #4 ***************
--- Model #1 out of 9 ---
    Parameters: lambda=[0.000]; alpha=[0.000] 
    RMSE: 146816.473

*************** Fold #5 ***************
--- Model #1 out of 9 ---
    Parameters: lambda=[0.000]; alpha=[0.000] 
    RMSE: 149868.621
```

As you can see, all the values of RMSE are below 150,000.
My expectation was that if I had taken the average of those values above, I would have got the first element of the `avgMetrics` list (which, indeed, supposedly contains the cross-validation average of each hyperparameter combination computed across the folds).
Instead, if I'm running `cv_model.avgMetrics` this is what I get:

```
[150091.7372030353, 150091.7372030353, 150091.7372030353, 150091.7345116686, 150093.66131828527, 150090.52769066638, 150091.7338301999, 150090.52716106002, 150091.59829053417]
```

There are 9 elements as expected but none of them looks correct! In fact, all of them are above 150,000 even though none of my 45 models (not only the 5 I listed above) reaches those figures.

It looks like the way in which `avgMetrics` is populated is wrong. I know there was an issue back in 2016 where this value mistakenly contained the sum of the cross validation metrics rather than the average but apparently this has been [fixed](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/14456).

I have also tried to inspect the [current implementation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/ml/tuning.html#CrossValidator) of the `_fit` method of the `CrossValidator` object and - although I haven't spent too much time on this - apparently everything looks fine:

```
for i in range(nFolds):
    validateLB = i * h
    validateUB = (i + 1) * h
    condition = (df[randCol] >= validateLB) & (df[randCol] < validateUB)
    validation = df.filter(condition).cache()
    train = df.filter(~condition).cache()

    tasks = _parallelFitTasks(est, train, eva, validation, epm, collectSubModelsParam)
    for j, metric, subModel in pool.imap_unordered(lambda f: f(), tasks):
        metrics[j] += (metric / nFolds)
        if collectSubModelsParam:
            subModels[i][j] = subModel
```

Has anyone else experienced the same issue?

**EDIT:** I have blindly assumed the problem (if any) is on the `avgMetrics` property; however, it might be that those averages are actually correct, whilst the individual metrics which I have printed out above by calling the `.summary.rootMeanSquaredError` on each submodel are computed wrongly. Either way, there is a clear inconsistency between the two.

Answer (score 1):

I have posted this question directly to the [Apache Spark github](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/14456#issuecomment-618318444) and I have been told what I was doing wrong.

I'm posting the answer here in case anyone has the same issue.

Basically, I thought I was printing out the individual RMSE as measured on the held-out (i.e., validation) portion of every (k) cross validation run. As a matter of fact, I was instead printing out the RMSE computed on the *training set* portion (of each fold).

Apparently, though, there is no easy way to recollect what I was trying to get, as that information seems not to be stored anyway. Good news is that the cross validation average makes sense.

Hope this helps.